Run and debug a C++ project compiled on WSL Ubuntu using make with VS 2022
I have to compile a C++ project using make and on a Ubuntu machine, due to it being provided that way.
I would like to still be able to use VS 2022 as an IDE since I know it relatively well and it got many useful features. But I can't use a solution, so it has to be a folder based project.
I have tried to use tasks and a custom launch.vs.json to be able to do these things, but I can't get it working. VS 2022 seems to not be able to run the program in WSL. I have never done this before, so I don't know if this is the best approach.
I have tried to make a custom tasks.vs.json and launch.vs.json file to tell VS 2022 how to compile my project. I have attached their content at the end.
When I try to launch the program in VS 2022, I get this error:
Starting: "wsl"  "/usr/bin/gdb --interpreter=mi"
/bin/bash: line 1: /usr/bin/gdb --interpreter=mi: No such file or directory
"wsl" exited with code 127 (0x7F).

What is wrong with my approach or how can I fix my setup? And is it even possible while staying in a folder based project? I know you can do it when creating an actual project in VS22 and not stay in a folder based project (with no .sln or .vcxproj files). But sadly that isn't an option for me.
launch.vs.json:
{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "defaults": {},
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "name": "WSL Launch",
      "request": "launch",
      "project": "main.exe",
      "program": "/mnt/c/Task1/main.exe",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "/mnt/c/Task1",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "pipeTransport": {
        "pipeCwd": "",
        "pipeProgram": "wsl",
        "pipeArgs": [],
        "debuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
      },
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ],
      "preLaunchTask": "build"
    }
  ]
}

tasks.vs.json:
{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "taskLabel": "Task-2024-14-10",
      "appliesTo": "/",
      "type": "launch"
    },
    {
      "taskName": "build",
      "appliesTo": ".*",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "wsl",
      "args": [
        "make"
      ],
      "label": "Build with WSL"
    },
    {
      "taskName": "run",
      "appliesTo": ".*",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "wsl",
      "args": [
        "./main.exe"
      ],
      "label": "Run Application in WSL"
    },
    {
      "taskLabel": "Task-2024-14-10",
      "appliesTo": "/",
      "type": "launch"
    },
    {
      "taskLabel": "Task-main",
      "appliesTo": "main.cpp",
      "type": "launch"
    },
    {
      "taskLabel": "Task-\u00DCbung 1",
      "appliesTo": "/",
      "type": "launch"
    }
  ]
}


Can you clarify what exactly your question is?

That looks more like you're using Visual Studio Code, which is an entirely different product from Visual Studio.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-build-debug-wsl2?view=msvc-170 would be a good place to start

@molbdnilo I think this is VS, vscode uses launch.json rather than launch.vs.json
